# Adequate sample size for non-normal population

Tags: sample-size, inverse-gaussian-distribution

There are 197,058 record holders (population) with an average of K shares each. I don’t know K, and the sample collected so far of ~24,000 observations appear to be non-normal (inverse gauss). I’m wondering how big the sample size would need to be such that the sample mean would be approximately equal to the population mean. There are many online statistics calculators, but none that factor in non-normal distributions.

Ultimately, I’m looking for  K x 197,058 = total number of shares held by record holders.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How many observations do I need such that my sample mean would be approximately equal to the population mean? Or what method should I use to determine the adequate size?

Comment: '*approximately equal to the population mean*' - you'll need to be more specific about what you mean by *approximately*. On the plus side, unless the distribution is *very* skewed/heavy tailed, the usual large sample normal approximation for the standardized sample mean should suffice. NB counts wont actually be inverse gaussian

Comment: Thank you so much for a reply! When I say "approximately equal to the population mean" I just mean close to the population mean. The following site says I need 15,351 observations to achieve 99% confidence w/ a 1% margin of error for the population (197,058), but I'm not sure how the non-normal distribution factors into that. https://www.surveysystem.com/sscalc.htm

Comment: I'm not sure what NB stands for though. The sample is pretty heavily skewed with an average of 600 and a median of 150.

Comment: NB = *nota bene*, i.e. 'note well' more or less

Comment: "Close" is just as vague as "approximately"; *more specific* means something akin to "99% coverage, 1% margin of error". In this case you're probably safe with the normal *as long as the sample represents a set of independent identically distributed draws from the population of interest* -- both those assumptions may be dubious. Also, if "record holders" implies that the values are the most extreme in some sample, you might have to worry about the distribution being potentially extremely right skew - indeed the samples may be large enough to consider extreme value distributions as models...ctd

Comment: ctd... Even if you do have i.i.d observations, it *might* still be the case that the (standardized) population third absolute moment ($E[|Z|^3]$ where $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$) is high enough that the normal doesn't work so well even at this large a sample size -- when the population absolute moments are really big, the corresponding sample moments may be inaccurate (and biased toward 0), so the sample might look more or less okay but may not provide as encouraging a picture as might be hoped.

Comment: I'd have posted an answer but I'm not sure I understand the situation clearly enough to be confident my answer is sensible.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your reply!